# What's wrong with my code? It's throwing so many errors on the browser

Tags: javascript, express, cors, fetch-api, body-parser

I'm new to JS and all these errors are doing my head in.

Basically, after clicking the "generate" button, a new entry under "Most Recent Entry" should display: the current temperature for the zip code entered, the current date, and the text that the user inputted for "how are you feeling today?"

But when I ran it on the browser, a bunch load of errors came up and I don't know how to fix them. I've installed node, cors, body-parser, and express, though they all came up with a number of vulnerabilities - so I don't know if that has to do with some functions not working.

This is what comes up in the console after I enter a zip code and some text:
[console errors on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWUk6.png)

Server side code:

```js
/* Create empty JS object */
projectData = {};

/* Setup Node environment */
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

/* Dependencies */
// Middle-ware
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

/* Initialize the main project folder */
app.use(express.static("website"));

/* Create server */
const port = 8000;
app.listen(port, listening);
function listening() {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
};

/* GET route */
app.get("/all", returnData);
function returnData(req, res) {
  res.send(projectData);
};

/* POST route */
const data = [];

app.post("/addData", addData);
function addData(req, res) {
  let newData = request.body;
  let newEntry = {
    temp: newData.temp,
    date: newData.date,
    content: newData.content,
  }
  data.push(newEntry);
};
```

Client side code:

```js
/* Async POST */
const postData = async (url = "", data = {}) => {
    console.log(data);
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", 
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },       
        body: JSON.stringify(data), 
    });

    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        return newData;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

/* Acquire API */
const zipCode =  document.getElementById("zip").value;
const userResponse = document.getElementById("feelings").value;
const apiKey = "4c603ee35d9242056474d3fbf69afec3";
const baseURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipCode},&appid=${apiKey}`;

let d = new Date();
let getDate = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear();

const getGenerate = document.getElementById("generate");
getGenerate.addEventListener("click", retrieveData);

/* GET request to API */
const getWeatherData = async(baseURL, zipCode, apiKey) => {
    const res = await fetch(baseURL + zipCode + apiKey);
    try {
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data)
    }  catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

/* Add API & User Data */
function retrieveData(e) {
    getWeatherData(baseURL, zipCode, apiKey)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        postData("/addData", 
        {temp: temp, date: getDate, content: userResponse});
    })
    .then(
        updateUI()
    )
}

/* Update UI */
const updateUI = async() => {
    const request = await fetch("/all");
    try {
        const allData = await request.json();
        console.log(allData);
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = allData[0].temp;
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = allData[0].date;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = allData[0].userInput;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
};
```

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE >
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Weather Journal</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600,700|Ranga:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id ="app">
    <div class="holder headline">Weather Journal App</div>
    <div class="holder zipcode">
      <label for="zc">Enter Zipcode here</label>
      <input type="text" id="zip" placeholder="enter zip code here">
    </div>
    <div class="holder userresponse">
      <label for="ur">How are you feeling today?</label>
      <textarea class="myInput" id="feelings" placeholder="enter your feelings here" rows="9" cols="50"></textarea>
      <button id="generate" type="submit">Generate</button>
    </div>
    <div class="holder entry">
      <div class="title">Most Recent Entry</div>
      <div id="entryHolder">
        <div id="date"></div> 
        <div id="temp"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../server.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

1. Your *"server side code"* is `server.js`
2. Your *"client side code"* is `website/app.js`
3. Your *"HTML code"* is `website/index.html`

**Problem #1** - `addData` doesn't send a response.

Any requests to `/addData` will never resolve.

Add a `res.send()` or equivalent call, eg

```js
res.json(newEntry); // assuming this should be the response
```

**Problem #2** - You're including your server-side code in the client-side HTML template.

Remove the `server.js` from your HTML template. I would also recommend using absolute paths for other static assets

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"> <!-- note the "/" -->

<!-- ... -->

<script src="/app.js"></script> <!-- note the "/" -->

<!-- remove this one
<script src="../server.js"></script>
-->
```

**Problem #3** - you appear to be opening your HTML file directly from the filesystem.

Instead, make sure you run your Express server...

```sh
node server.js
```

and open the URL it serves at `http://localhost:8000/`.

**Problem #4** - Your `baseURL` already includes `zipCode` and `apiKey`.

There's no need to append them to the `fetch()` URL.

---

Other improvements...

1. The `body-parser` library is no longer required. If you're following a tutorial it is out-of-date. Find a new one or follow the [official Express guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)
2. Always register the `cors()` middleware first. Any errors in other middleware will break your CORS integrations and you won't be able to receive responses

   ```js
   app.use(cors()); // cors first

   // built-in body parsing
   app.use(express.json());
   app.use(express.urlencoded());
   ```

Comment: I did the recommended changes and the errors lessened, but now it shows "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" and "POST http://localhost:8000/addData 500 (Internal Server Error)". The other errors I can deal with, but I have no idea what's wrong these two now.

Comment: The first error is from some browser extension you're running, nothing to do with your code. The second can be debugged by looking at the logging from your Express server.